# Issues while setting up ArangoDB Cluster

Tags: arangodb, database, nosql

Recently I was trying to setup a development cluster on my local machine in ArangoDB.

I tried to create a cluster through the web interface, I got this error stating:

> "**Error while starting the cluster: Unauthorized**".

The first time I tried doing it, it doesn't show any error, but kept asking for username and password again and again, and shows:

> **Coordinator User invalid**.

My ArangoDB version is **2.6.8**

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ArangoDB Cluster abilities are migrated to Apache Mesos cluster management.
The webinterface as you're currently using will only remain for evaluation purposes. Thus authentication will not be supported on it.

Please retry without authentication by specifying

```
 --server.disable-authentication true
```

on the commandline or by configuring arangod.conf like that:

```
[server]
disable-authentication=true
```