# ArangoDB - Asymmetrical clustering doesn't work

Tags: configuration, cluster-computing, arangodb

i've installed an arangodb instance on a virtual machine of Google Cloud (`tcp://10.240.0.2`). I would setup an asymmetrical cluster with another vm where i've installed arangodb (`tcp://10.240.0.3`).

I follow the official guide to config the production scenario: 1 coordinator and 1 DBServer on the same machine

I tried also a second configuration to cluster with two vm instances, but it doesn't work, showing this error in the GoogleChromeConsole :

```
{"error":true,"code":500,"errorNum":500,
"errorMessage":"Cannot check port on dispatcher tcp://10.240.0.3:8529"}
```

[Here you can find the configurations that I have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xVbZ.png)

What could be the error?

PS: I've open in the firewall the ports: 8529,8530,8629

Thanks in advance.

Daniele

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed ArangoDB on both virtual machines and changed the configuration (on both) to set

```
[cluster]
  disable-dispatcher-kickstarter = false
  disable-dispatcher-frontend = false
```

and then restarted the database servers? I assume so, since you get "Connection OK" for both servers. Your browser would then talk to the first dispatcher, which in turn will contact the second one. The error message you get suggests that this latter step does not work, since checking ports is the first request the first dispatcher would send to the second one.

Is it possible that processes in the first VM cannot access `tcp://10.240.0.3:8529` on the second VM? Maybe the respective other subnets are not routed from within the VMs?

Furthermore, when you have got this to work, you will almost certainly also need port 4001 on the first VM, because that is where our etcd (Agency) will listen. In addition, the ports 8530 and 8629 are the defaults which are tried first. If they are not usable for some reason, the dispatchers will use subsequent port numbers instead to assign them to the coordinators and DBservers. In that case you would have to open these as well, at least from the respective other VM.

Comment: Yes, I installed arangodb enabling frontend and kickstarter.
The VMs can communicate each others, because the ports are opened between their. I've tried also to connect to arangosh from VM1 to VM2 and it works.

Comment: I also inspect the code of arangodb and I see that the first VM1 cannot get this URL of the VM2 `http://10.240.0.3:8529/_admin/clusterCheckPort?port=8529`. I tried with wget and I see the 403 error (forbidden). Can this be the problem?

Comment: Looking again at the screenshot you sent, I come to the conclusion that you have not entered the user and password in the input fields for the second dispatcher. Therefore you get authentication problems between the two dispatchers. The fact that it says "Connection Ok" is a bug in the display. I would assume that if you put user and password there as well,  you should be able to launch a cluster.

Comment: However, there is further bad news coming: Some investigations have shown that we currently do not support the cluster dashboard at all when authentication is turned on. This is essentially due to the fact that we currently are moving our cluster management over to Apache Mesos and the "old" method involving dispatchers will be obsolete soon. It is essentially only considered to be usable for experiments without authentication right now. Therefore I recommend to switch off authentication in your dispatchers and the problems should go away. Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32839924/issues-while-setting-up-arangodb-cluster

Comment: In your opinion, can I use this clustering methods? https://github.com/arangodb/deployment

Comment: This repository contains the scripts which we have published in https://www.arangodb.com/2015/04/digital-ocean-cluster/ , https://www.arangodb.com/2015/04/gce-cluster/ , https://www.arangodb.com/2015/05/aws-cluster/  and https://www.arangodb.com/2015/05/azure-cluster/ and they should work to set up ArangoDB clusters, if not, please report an issue in the repo.

Comment: Furthermore, it contains a script to set up an Apache Mesos cluster on which deployment of an ArangoDB cluster is also possible using our Mesos framework scheduler currently being developed here: https://github.com/ArangoDB/arangodb-mesos , however, this is work in progress and I am currently hacking away at it. For the official release 2.8 there will be official instructions on how to use this.

Comment: Finally, ArangoDB is a certified Mesosphere service http://mesosphere.com also using Apache Mesos and our framework scheduler. So if you run a Mesosphere cluster with the Mesosphere DCOS, you can install an ArangoDB cluster with a single command, see https://github.com/ArangoDB/arangodb-dcos